# Access files from Microsoft Teams tab app

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I'm currently building a custom teams tab app for the channel to upload a file and search the file by contents within the files. It seems Teams files tab using SharePoint to store the files. Is it possible to access the files uploaded in the teams channel (which is there in files tab) in my custom teams tab app? So that I can leverage the search feature to files within the files tab.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the sharepoint search API (you can limit your search to look only in the particular site/team). Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-files